# How can i make expandable GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I'm making an app which contains GridView. GridView collects data from Amazon S3 server and Glide library shows images to users. However, I have problem with it.

[Image 1; before button clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB3gx.png)

[Image 2; After button clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ir92.png)

I want make Gridview is expandable when one button is clicked. I've tried to make layout expand, but it didn't work. Is there another way to get this?

Comment: If you have two destinc seperate questions, please split them in two! Also note that the more valueable information you supply in your question, the better the answers become. Also i am quite sure questions involving the Button class to have Text-Labels are andwered here already quite often.

Answer (score 0):

You can set onClickListener in your button..

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnShowFinanceSector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Ofertar" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

in your Activity after inflate layout:

```
    this.btnShowFinanceSector= (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnShowFinanceSector);
    this.btnShowFinanceSector.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //DO SOMETHING
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

set tag to button. in .xml or .java

```
button.setTage("Finance");
```

then you can check it by calling `getTag();`